# How to reference an xml node by an index variable in UFT?

Tags: vbscript, qtp, hp-uft

I have many xml files that I am trying to edit.  The first node I want to edit is located at the top of all the files, and is easily changeable.  The 2nd node is of a variable index, depending on which file I am trying to edit.  I can easily locate the node, and even edit the correct node if I reference it by a number.  But, I cannot edit the node if I reference it by a counter variable.  Is this possible using UFT?  Below is what I have so far.

```
'Create a blank XML document for copying and load xxx.xml file
Set xmlDoc = _
  CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
xmlDoc.Async = "False"
xmlDoc.Load("G:\xxx\xxx.xml")

'Change the sw version listed at the top of the file to 999
Set colNodes=xmlDoc.selectNodes _
  ("/Device/Model/SoftwareVersion")

For Each objNode in colNodes
   objNode.Text = "999"
Next

'Obtain the part number of the software version  
Set swNode=xmlDoc.selectNodes _
  ("/Device/Model/PartNumber")

For Each objNode in swNode
   swPartNumber = objNode.Text
Next

counter = 0

'Set up var to search through all nodes with strucutre Device/MSM/UpdateFile
Set updateFileNodes=xmlDoc.selectNodes _
  ("/Device/MassStorageMode/UpdateFile")    

'Set up var for updatefile block of major to edit later
Set majorSwNode = xmlDoc.selectNodes _
  ("/Device/MassStorageMode/UpdateFile/Version/Major")  

'Set up var for partnumber block of updatefile to search against for a math
Set partNumberNode = xmlDoc.selectNodes _
    ("/Device/MassStorageMode/UpdateFile/PartNumber")  

For Each objNode in updateFileNodes  

    For Each objNode2 in partNumberNode

        counter = counter + 1
        curPn = objNode2.Text

        isFound = swPartNumber = curPn

                If isFound = True Then 

                Dim index
                index = counter - 1

                'edit the major sw version here...  
                Set editNode = xmlDoc.selectsinglenode ("/Device/MassStorageMode/UpdateFile[counter]/Version/Major")

                editNode.Text = "9"
                xmlDoc.Save "G:\xxx\xxx.xml"                
                Exit For
                End If      
    Next    
Next
```

I get an error when I run this, however, if I change the line:

Set editNode = xmlDoc.selectsinglenode ("/Device/MassStorageMode/UpdateFile[125]/Version/Major")

using the value of my index variable in this particular case, everything performs as expected.  I need to be able to replace the number with my index variable.

Comment: This code doesn't seem to use any specific QTP/UFT capabilities, I think you should re-tag it as `vbscript`

Answer (score 0):

You need concatenation (&) to splice a variable's content into a string:

```
>> counter = 125
>> s = "/Device/MassStorageMode/UpdateFile[counter]/Version/Major"
>> WScript.Echo 1, s
>> s = "/Device/MassStorageMode/UpdateFile[" & counter & "]/Version/Major"
>> WScript.Echo 2, s
>>
1 /Device/MassStorageMode/UpdateFile[counter]/Version/Major
2 /Device/MassStorageMode/UpdateFile[125]/Version/Major
```

Comment: That worked like a charm.  Thanks so much for the help.